# Content in child div is overlapping the parent div

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

The content of my conversation lists is overlapping and I can't seem to debug it. I am using vue and the code is here together with the css and image. What i want to happen is in the expected result image where the content will stay inside the div of the card and just like in messenger, if the text is too long, it will not display the complete text.

```
<v-flex lg3 id="convolist-container" class="fill-height">
  <div id="convo-container" v-else>
    <div id="convo-container" v-for="chat in chats" :key="chat.chat_entry_id">
      <v-card max-height="150" v-on:click="displayChat(chat.service_order_id, chat.user_to, chat.user_from)">
        <v-layout id="convo-container" class="no-gutters" row lg3>
          <v-flex lg3 md3 xs3>
            <v-avatar class="mt-2 ml-2" size="36">
              <img :src=chat.prof_pic alt="Jihyo">
            </v-avatar>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex lg6 md6 xs6>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex>
                {{chat.fullname}}
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex>
                {{chat.message}}
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex lg3 md3 xs3>
            {{chat.datetimestamp}}
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-flex>
```

CSS

```
 #convolist-container{
        height: 650px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1%;
        border-color: lightgrey;
    }

#convo-container{
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

[image: convo-lists]
[image: expected-result]

Comment: yea, beause you set `height: 50px`

Comment: @Ifaruki how will i be able to achieve the expected result?

Comment: remove height propery and max-height and set `min-height: 50px` and see what happens

Comment: @Ifaruki nothing happened, it still overlaps the parent div..

Comment: Just a hunch since I can't test it, Put `white-space: nowrap` in your `#convo-container` also `height: 50px; max-height: 150px;` is useless since you put static height, max-height wont be satisfied.. I think what you want to put there is `min-height` and not `height`

Comment: should i do something with how i display the message of the person? @masterpreenz

Answer (score 0):

I added the white-space: nowrap and set the min-height to 50px to the #convo-container. Added a reference id for #convo-container p { text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; }